# accessing data returned from socket in swift using socket.io

Tags: swift, socket.io

I've got the following to listen for new 'message' events with the use of Socket.IO

```swift
self.socket.on("message") {data, ack in
            print("received data: \(data)")
            // do stuff
        }
```

Data I'm getting back in `data` looks as follows:

```
[{
    conversationid = 1;
    message = hello world;
    senderid = 1;
}]
```

It's an array holding a single object but I'm struggling to access the individual elements in there. For example:

```swift
let message = ???
```

Many thanks!

Comment: something like data[0].message?

Comment: @john elemans: thought so too first but getting `Value of type 'Any' has no member 'message'`

Comment: Then you have to cast the return the correct data type first. try let x = data[0] as! MyType.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Played around with it a bit more.
The following works:

```swift
let socketResponse = data[0] as? NSDictionary
let message = socketResponse!["message"]
```

While that solution makes sense to me, it still doesn't make sense why e.g. the solution that @0x0010b suggested doesn't. That one seemed perfectly sound to me as well. Grateful for anyone input that can shed some light on this one ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Your data's type is `[[String : Any]]`, if you wanna get the message try this:

Swift 5.x:

```
if let data = data as? [[String : Any]] {

    let message = data[0]["message"] as? String ?? ""
    print(message)
}
```

In this [repo](https://github.com/socketio/socket.io-client-swift) you have more info about how to implement socket.io

Comment: Thanks for your input!! I had also tried your solution before. But here I'm getting the following error: `Value of type 'Any' has no subscripts`.